# Azure DevOps Api throwing error: How to exchange approver?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have an Azure Pipeline with PowerShell code, which can dynamically exchange the approver for the different deployment stages. The approvers are exchanged by [using the API](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/(Organization)/(Project)/_apis/release/releases/(ReleaseID)?api-version=6.0). The code was working for a few runs, but somehow it broke without me having made any changes. Now, I am receiving the error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: 
{
  "$id":"1",
  "innerException":null,
  "message":"VS402865: An empty body in the POST request is not allowed.",
  "typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data",
  "typeKey":"InvalidRequestException",
  "errorCode":0,
  "eventId":3000
}
```

Is anyone else receiving the same error? Is it an Azure DevOps problem?

Comment: Check with Pat Token or authentication details

Comment: In the Pipeline itself I'm using the OAuth token provided by the pipeline (which is generated for each run). While testing code in Powershell I'm using a PAT with B64 transformation and full access to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for that endpoint at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0, that endpoint accepts a `GET` request. The error message suggests that you're issuing a `POST`.

Take a second look at the command line you're using for `Invoke-WebRequest`. I know you mentioned that no code changed, but it's definitely worth checking. If that doesn't fix it, I'd dump out header and URL values of what you're issuing with `Write-Host` and inspect the result in the build output.